# How to change the markup of a content entity in the Views UI?

Tags: views, theming, 8

Sorry if this has been asked already, I haven't seen anything yet exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm using the Views UI in Drupal 8 to output a list of a custom content entity type that I created via a custom module. I'd like to know what's the best way to programatically alter the markup of the entire entity.

I know that to do this with a field belonging to the entity you would use {module}\src\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\{formattername}.php and this would appear as an option for displaying a field, but is there a way to do this for the whole entity rather than just a field?

If there are any articles on this topic anyone could recommend I would greatly appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Yes. Output the view result as a view Mode and not as fields, then supply the markup for the view Mode twig template + fields as normal. Views will respect that and use it instead of  of the view rendering fields by itself.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Kevin, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "Output the view result as a view Mode". Does this refer to the "Format" section of the display settings? Under the "Show" setting there the only options I see are Fields, [entity class name], and Search.

Comment: Nodes have a "Content" format that lets you select the view mode to render as. I assume by "custom content type" you don't mean you created a new node type, because this option is available on a Node based view.

Comment: Correct, it is a custom entity that doesn't extend the node type.